# Unable to fill in site column entry

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, site-column

SharePoint online seems broken as I'm unable to use terms from the existing site columns i.e. not in document properties side view/grid view.

I can create a sub folder in the document library and there it still works.

Initially, it worked at root level as well and no permission changes have been made.

One moment it worked (while uploading documents), and then suddenly it is not accepting.

Any idea?

**P.S.** The terms doesn't contain space.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the term in the Managed Metadata Site column cannot be updated?

If possible, please provide detaield information such as screenshot for further troubleshooting.

In addition, create a new library to add the site column to check if the issue still exists.

Comment: the problem is in one document library, one person cannot update or add labels to documents. I'm more worried about it as this could happen to anyone and thus make our prime goal of using sharepoint (get rid of personal folder structures) a weak goal.
Permission wise its all correctly setup, the case is handed over to MS now

Comment: You could update your post if there is any solution from Microsoft support.It will do great help to those who meet the similar question in this forum.

Comment: if it gets resolved yes